# Unable to run experiment on Azure ML Studio after copying from different workspace

Tags: powershell, azure, machine-learning, azure-powershell, azure-machine-learning-service

My simple experiment reads from an Azure Storage Table, Selects a few columns and writes to another Azure Storage Table. This experiment runs fine on the Workspace (Let's call it workspace1).

Now I need to move this experiment as is to another workspace(Call it WorkSpace2) using Powershell and need to be able to run the experiment. 
I am currently using this Library - https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps

Problem :

When I Copy the experiment using 'Copy-AmlExperiment' from WorkSpace 1 to WorkSpace 2, the experiment and all it's properties get copied except the Azure Table Account Key. 
Now, this experiment runs fine if I manually enter the account Key for the Import/Export Modules on studio.azureml.net

But I am unable to perform this via powershell. If I Export(Export-AmlExperimentGraph) the copied experiment from WorkSpace2 as a JSON and insert the AccountKey into the JSON file and Import(Import-AmlExperiment) it into WorkSpace 2. The experiment fails to run.

On PowerShell I get an "Internal Server Error : 500".

While running on studio.azureml.net, I get the notification as "Your experiment cannot be run because it has been updated in another session. Please re-open this experiment to see the latest version."

Is there anyway to move an experiment with external dependencies to another workspace and run it?

Edit : I think the problem is something to do with how the experiment handles the AccountKey. When I enter it manually, it's converted into a JSON array comprising of RecordKey and IndexInRecord. But when I upload the JSON experiment with the accountKey, it continues to remain the same and does not get resolved into RecordKey and IndexInRecord.

Answer (score 0):

For me publishing the experiment as a private experiment for the cortana gallery is one of the most useful options. Only the people with the link can see and add the experiment for the gallery. On the below link I've explained the steps I followed.

https://naadispeaks.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/copying-migrating-azureml-experiments/

Comment: This does not solve the problem of the AccountKey right? The accountKeys are not copied over to the new workspace even when copied from Cortana Library.

Comment: Haven't tried it. How about setting the account keys as a web service parameter and insert them when calling to the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

When the experiment is copied, the pwd is wiped for security reasons. If you want to programmatically inject it back, you have to set another metadata field to signal that this is a plain-text password, not an encrypted password that you are setting. If you export the experiment in JSON format, you can easily figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue why you are unable to export the credentials back.

Export the JSON graph into your local disk, then update whatever parameter has to be updated.

Also, you will notice that the credentials are stored as 'Placeholders' instead of 'Literals'. Hence it makes sense to change them to Literals instead of placeholders.

This you can do by traversing through the JSON to find the relevant parameters you need to update.

Here is a brief illustration.

#### Changing the Placeholder to a Literal:

[image: Changing the Placeholder to a Literal]